# How to do 'NOT' in regex?

Tags: java, regex, split

Im trying to use the Split Function in Java. The character i'm trying to split at is `;`.

So my code is like this:

```
string.split(";");
```

However, inside the string I have many escaped `\;`. I wanted to a regex which would not split at `\;` but only split at where the `;` is on its own.

Example of String:

```
sometexthere\;shhshshshhs;shhshshshshs\;dddddd;
```

Expected Result:

```
[0] sometexthere\;shhshshshhs;
[1] shhshshshshs\;dddddd;
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will there be something like `sometext\\;somemoretext`? What is the expected result, then?

Comment: As you write the String it has invalid escape sequence and it is not acceptable by the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
str.split("(?<!\\\\);");
```

**EDIT**

if you do want to have the spliter (the `;`) in result array:

```
str.split("(?<=[^\\\\];)");
```

Note that single look-behind is sufficient for this problem.

and this time, I did a test:

```
final String str = "sometexthere\\;shhshshshhs;shhshshshshs\\;dddddd;";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("(?<=[^\\\\];)")));
```

it outputs:

```
[sometexthere\;shhshshshhs;, shhshshshshs\;dddddd;]
```

Comment: `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`. To specify `(?<!\\)` in raw regex, you need to write `(?<!\\\\)` in Java literal string

Comment: It throws PatternSyntaxException in my machine.

Comment: @nhahtdh yep, I didn't test it, forgot to escape **every** backslash.... thanks. fixed

Comment: Just noticed that Pshemo's solution produces the expected result, while yours will remove the `;`.

Comment: @nhahtdh ah.. thx, I didn't notice the semi was still there. add a solution.

Comment: @Kent Thanks for your help but i wanted to ask if there was a way to remove the \`\\` after the splitting has been completed so im left with just `[sometexthere;shhshshshhs;, shhshshshshs;dddddd;]`

Comment: @user2470746 I cannot see it could be done with split. after split, you could replace all `\;` to `;`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `split("(?<=(?<!\\\\);)")` if you don't want to remove `;` but just split after it. We are using here double [look-behind mechanisms](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

- positive look-behind `(?<=...)`
- negative look-behind `(?<!...)`

`(?<=;)` will find places that has `;` before it, but we also have to make sure that `;` doesn't have `\` before, so we can write it as `(?<=(?<!\\\\);)`.

Comment: instead of nested look-behind, `[^\\]`(raw string) could be used .

Comment: @Kent yes, I saw it in your answer :) but since there is no point in duplicating answers I wont include this info in mine but will leave it as it is to show alternative way.

Comment: no problem. to be honest, this is the first time I see a nested look-behind expression. ;) good to know there is another way leading to Rome.

Comment: @Kent Anyway I just hope that OP wont use `;` at start of his data because your current regex will not split on it even if there is no \ before it.